# Return JSON string in a normal way

Tags: c#, .net

From one method I'm getting string like that one:

```
"{\n  \"Name\": \"Next steps for pathway activities\",\n  \"Options\": [\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Show next steps\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Treatment cannot continue\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"treatment\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Refer to GP\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"refer_to_gp\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"New Wax appointment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"new_wax_appointment_otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Continue treatment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"pathway-activities\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"
```

How can I parse it to a normal format?
(P.S. It is not required to be as a string as a result, it also can be some dynamic object)

Comment: This looks like a valid JSON. You can check the `Json.NET - Newtonsoft` nuget package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: What do you consider to be a "normal format"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an object and perform operations on this object in the future you can use Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package.

Just create classes that reflects your json like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Option> Options { get; set; }

}

class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

And try deserialize this json:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Like this you will get an object**

```
let myStr = "{\n  \"Name\": \"Next steps for pathway activities\",\n  \"Options\": [\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Show next steps\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Treatment cannot continue\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"treatment\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Refer to GP\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"refer_to_gp\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"New Wax appointment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"new_wax_appointment_otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Continue treatment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"pathway-activities\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";
```

`let myObj = JSON.parse(myStr);`

`console.log(myObj);`

**The output will be:**

```
    "Name": "Next steps for pathway activities",
    "Options": [
        {
            "Name": "Show next steps",
            "ActionType": "PathSelector",
            "Key": "otoscopy",
            "Group": "pathway-activities"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Treatment cannot continue",
            "ActionType": "Navigation",
            "Key": "treatment",
            "Group": "pathway-activities"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Refer to GP",
            "ActionType": "PathSelector",
            "Key": "refer_to_gp",
            "Group": "treatment"
        },
        {
            "Name": "New Wax appointment",
            "ActionType": "PathSelector",
            "Key": "new_wax_appointment_otoscopy",
            "Group": "treatment"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Continue treatment",
            "ActionType": "Navigation",
            "Key": "pathway-activities",
            "Group": "treatment"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this take you **json** string

```
var myStr = "{\n  \"Name\": \"Next steps for pathway activities\",\n  \"Options\": [\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Show next steps\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Treatment cannot continue\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"treatment\",\n      \"Group\": \"pathway-activities\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Refer to GP\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"refer_to_gp\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"New Wax appointment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"PathSelector\",\n      \"Key\": \"new_wax_appointment_otoscopy\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Name\": \"Continue treatment\",\n      \"ActionType\": \"Navigation\",\n      \"Key\": \"pathway-activities\",\n      \"Group\": \"treatment\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

var _obj = JSON.parse(myStr);

console.log(_obj);
```

OutPut in Image

[image]